# How to find the convex hull of a 3D facet in R

Tags: r, 3d

Is there a way to find the vertices of a facet in R given a set of points (the facet is the convex hull of the points and is of dimension 2). That is, how to define function `convexHull`:

```
vertices<-matrix(c(0,0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,2), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)  # ex1
vertices<-matrix(c(1,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,1,1), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)  # ex2 (updated question)
vertices # one vertex in each row.
convexHull(vertices)  # should return indices 1,3,4 (vertex 1,3 and 4 since vertex 2 is a convex combination of 1 and 3)
```

Comment: Since all points lie on the x = 0 plane `chull(vertices[, 2], vertices[, 3])` .
`

Comment: Yes this works in the case where all of one of the coordinates is zero. But should work for general planes too, e.g.:

`vertices<-matrix(c(1,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,1,1), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)`

Comment: If you know the points all lie in a plane, then @G.Grothendieck's solution still works for every plane but one.  So just try it twice, e.g. `unique(c(chull(vertices[,1:2]), chull(vertices[,2:3])))`.

Comment: The one it not will work for is e.g. `vertices<-matrix(c(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,0), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)`. However, your hint is right. We just have to make some kind of projection where all vertices are unique. I have added my implementation of `convexHull`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user2554330 for hints.

```
convexHull <- function(points) {
    points <- unique(points)
    l <- dim(points)[1]
    n <- dim(points)[2]
    comb <- t(combn(n,2))
    for (i in 1:dim(comb)[1]) {  # simple projection down on each axis
      p <- unique(points[,comb[i,]])
      if (l == dim(p)[1]) {
        return(chull(points[,comb[i,]]))
      }
    }
    stop("Cannot find the vertices!")
}
```